# Consulta COUNT en mi Dashboard

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen Dia, espero y puedan apoyarme, tengo mi dashboard pero quiero que me muestre el numero de registros de usuarios que tengo guardado en mi BD, ya tengo la consulta pero quisiera saber como implementarla.

Codigo HTML.

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
              <div class="card card-statistics">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="float-left">
                      <i class="mdi mdi-account-location text-info icon-lg"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                      <p class="mb-0 text-right">Usuarios</p>
                      <div class="fluid-container">
                        <h3 class="font-weight-medium text-right mb-0"></h3>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="text-muted mt-3 mb-0">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-reload mr-1" aria-hidden="true">Aqui Irian el Numero de Usuarios</i> Product-wise sales
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Codigo PHP.

```
<?php
    $consultaS=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) from users;");
    while($rS=mysqli_fetch_array($consultaS)){
            $users=$rS['users'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si haces una consulta count eso solo te traera un resultado por tanto el ciclo while esta de más, el otro detalle es que debes capturar esa cantidad en una variable y agregarla a tu html con echo como te muestro a continuación:

```
<?php
    $consultaS=mysqli_query($conexion,"select count(*) as count from users;");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaS))
?>

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
  <div class="card card-statistics">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="float-left">
          <i class="mdi mdi-account-location text-info icon-lg"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
          <p class="mb-0 text-right">Usuarios</p>
          <div class="fluid-container">
            <h3 class="font-weight-medium text-right mb-0"></h3>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="text-muted mt-3 mb-0">
        <i class="mdi mdi-reload mr-1" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo $row['count']; ?> Product-wise sales
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```